# Re-Route network calls to multiple domains through SSH tunnel in windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, ssh, proxy, tunnel

I have the following situation: There are some hosts that are only accessible through an ssh tunnel. Lets say its

- https://example.com
- https://other.com

I can establish the SSH tunnel and bind the 443 ports needed for the connection to local ports:

```
ssh -L 1443:example.com:443 -L 2443:other.com:443 -A -l username myproxy.com
```

This works fine so far - when I call `https://localhost:1443`, I can open example.com, if I call `https://localhost:2443`, I can call other.com

The problem: There are some apps that are not aware of this and still try to connect via the regular hostname and port.

Adding the following lines to my `hosts` file, I can get a step closer to the final solution:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 other.com
```

This enables me to call `https://example.com:1443` and `https://other.com:2443` in my browser - but the port is still a problem. I would need to map BOTH domains to my local port `443` to make it work for other applications.

I guess I will need to have a local proxy server listening on port `443` and forwarding traffic based on hostname to either `1443` or `2443` but this is where I'm lost.

What can I do to enable all apps on my machine to just use the hostname/port but let the traffic go over my SSH tunnel?

Comment: SSH can create a TAP device, and you could route the ips through that.

Comment: Do you have a document at hand which describes how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh -D`. This will create a SOCKS 5 proxy server on the specified port (usually 1080 or 9050), which you can configure in the browser and access *everything* through the SSH tunnel.

This works identically with OpenSSH, PuTTY (plink), Bitvise Tunnelier; and does not depend on any operating system-level features.

For example, with `ssh -D 9050` running, you can configure Firefox like this:

[image]

(Chrome might need a [command-line option](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/socks-proxy) instead.)